# Is there a way to rank across a record?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, rank

I'm trying to do a rank (?) across columns where a "Favorites" column is based on the highest value in specified columns.

How the current dataset is:

| user | Tops Bought | pants bought |
| --- | --- | --- |
| anna | 50 | 12 |
| jon | 12 | 50 |

& What would like to do is this :

| user | Tops Bought | pants bought | favorite item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| anna | 50 | 12 | tops |
| jon | 12 | 50 | pants |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(tops_bought, pants_bought)
            when tops_bought then 'tops'
            when pans_bought then 'pants'
        end) as favorite_item
from t;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Do you happen to know if there's a way to then rank these? For example first_fav_item = pants, second_fav_item = pants?

Comment: @marni101 . . . That gets more complicated, especially in Redshift.